# Ubuntu's default Firefox does not play videos on after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, firefox, snap

A few days ago Ubuntu (22.04 LTS) showed me a message saying I can upgrade my OS (or something along those lines). I click on agree (any button that would let me proceed) and the upgrade took place (without restarting). Along with the upgrade Firefox was also updated to its latest version at the time (119.0). Since then, videos on Twitter play but without sound. On some other websites also none of the videos play. On YouTube, Firefox shows me a message saying “To play video, you may need to install the required video codecs” but the videos play fine; I haven’t tried other websites but I assume all would have some issues. Google Chrome however doesn’t have this issue and all videos play without any issues.

Note that I restarted my computer after the upgrade but this didn’t resolve the issue either.

I did the followings and restarted Firefox but none have worked so far for Twitter and some other random websites that I come across, but they resolved the issue for YouTube and now YouTube videos play, although I still get that codec message at the top of the tab:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
```

Until today I didn’t know you can install things on Ubuntu 22 as a snap package and that by default, Firefox is a “snap” package on Ubuntu 22. So I also did the following and installed ffmpeg as a snap package but still have the same issue after restarting Firefox.

```
sudo snap install ffmpeg
```

Could you help me figure out what I should do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have ffmpeg installed, install the [libavcodec package](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-updates-universe-arm64/libavcodec-extra_4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_arm64.deb.html).